Typescript Type Alias With Fixed and Dynamic Members
I would like to have a type where it has a defined set of keys with a defined type, but also allow any other properties be added to it with their type being of the type that those keys belong to... ie:
type ResourceRouteGroupBase = {
    list?: string;
    view?: string;
    edit?: string;
    create?: string;
    delete?: string;
} 

type ResourceRouteGroup = ResourceRouteGroupBase & {
    [key:string]: ResourceRouteGroupBase
}




const group:ResourceRouteGroup = {
    list:'',
    view:'',
    emailRouteGroup:{list:'',create:''}
}


TS doesn't support this directly, see the linked q/a for more information and various approaches
